# CSS Grid template area not working correctly with flex child

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I have a problem when using `display:flex` inside of one of the `grid-template-area` elements. Particularly, what I'm struggling to understand is why the behaviour that I'm seeing is different when using `grid-template-columns` vs `grid-template-area`.

Here's my example, the first box is created using `grid-template-columns` and the second one uses `grid-template-area`. The blue part is a flex element:

[image]

Number 1 uses:

`grid-template-columns: 2fr 5fr;`

Number 2 uses:

```
grid-template-areas: 
    "stage-left2 stage-left2 stage-right2 stage-right2 stage-right2 stage-right2 stage-right2";
```

Shouldn't they be equivalent to one another since they are both in 2:5 ratio?

And another question, why in the second example the yellow zone shrinks down instead of keeping the size equal to 2/7 as it does in the first example? This seems to have something to do with the fact that the blue zone is a flex element. When flex property is removed from there then the yellow zone goes back to the correct size.

```css
#plan-container{
max-width: 500px;
}

.stage {
    display: grid;
     grid-template-columns: 2fr 5fr;
    border-bottom: 3px solid grey;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;

    
}

.stage-left {
    background-color: yellow;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 4fr 2fr;
  text-align: center;
  
}

.stage-right {
    background-color: aqua;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 20px;
}


.stage2 {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "stage-left2 stage-left2 stage-right2 stage-right2 stage-right2 stage-right2 stage-right2";
    border-bottom: 3px solid grey;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;

    
}

.stage-left2{
grid-area: stage-left2;
background-color: yellow;
display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 4fr 2fr;
  text-align: center;

}

.stage-right2{
    grid-area: stage-right2;
    background-color: aqua;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 20px;
}




.plan-element {
    height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
      border: 1px solid #555;
      
    }
    
    .add-plan-element {
        background-color: aqua;
    }

    .stage-left-numbering {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }
    
    .stage-left-numbering p {
    font-size: 40px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="plan-container">

        <div class="stage">
            <div class="stage-left">
                <div class="stage-left-numbering">
                    <p>1</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="stage-right">
                <div class="plan-element">
                </div>
                <div class="plan-element">
                </div>
                <div class="plan-element">
                </div>
                <div class="plan-element">
                </div>
                <div class="plan-element">
                </div>
                <div class="plan-element">
                </div>
                <div class="plan-element">
                </div>
                <div class="plan-element add-plan-element">
                    <p>ADD</p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="stage2">
            <div class="stage-left2">
                <div class="stage-left-numbering">
                    <p>2</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="stage-right2">
                <div class="plan-element">
                </div>
                <div class="plan-element">
                </div>
                <div class="plan-element">
                </div>
                <div class="plan-element">
                </div>
                <div class="plan-element">
                </div>
                <div class="plan-element">
                </div>
                <div class="plan-element">
                </div>
                <div class="plan-element add-plan-element">
                    <p>ADD</p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>




    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: In the first example, the widths of the two columns are defined with `grid-template-columns`. In the second example, the widths of the columns are NOT defined, so the columns adjust to fit the content. Your assumption about the 2:5 ratio is flawed because `grid-template-areas` does not automatically create columns with equal width.

Answer (score 6):

> The [`grid-auto-columns`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-columns) CSS property specifies the size of an implicitly-created grid column track or pattern of tracks.

So need to set `.stage2 { grid-auto-columns: 1fr; }`:

```css
#plan-container{
max-width: 500px;
}

.stage {
    display: grid;
     grid-template-columns: 2fr 5fr;
    border-bottom: 3px solid grey;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;

    
}

.stage-left {
    background-color: yellow;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 4fr 2fr;
  text-align: center;
  
}

.stage-right {
    background-color: aqua;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 20px;
}


.stage2 {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "stage-left2 stage-left2 stage-right2 stage-right2 stage-right2 stage-right2 stage-right2";
    border-bottom: 3px solid grey;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    grid-auto-columns: 1fr; /*  */
}

.stage-left2{
grid-area: stage-left2;
background-color: yellow;
display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 4fr 2fr;
  text-align: center;

}

.stage-right2{
    grid-area: stage-right2;
    background-color: aqua;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 20px;
}




.plan-element {
    height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
      border: 1px solid #555;
      
    }
    
    .add-plan-element {
        background-color: aqua;
    }

    .stage-left-numbering {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }
    
    .stage-left-numbering p {
    font-size: 40px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="plan-container">

        <div class="stage">
            <div class="stage-left">
                <div class="stage-left-numbering">
                    <p>1</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="stage-right">
                <div class="plan-element">
                </div>
                <div class="plan-element">
                </div>
                <div class="plan-element">
                </div>
                <div class="plan-element">
                </div>
                <div class="plan-element">
                </div>
                <div class="plan-element">
                </div>
                <div class="plan-element">
                </div>
                <div class="plan-element add-plan-element">
                    <p>ADD</p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="stage2">
            <div class="stage-left2">
                <div class="stage-left-numbering">
                    <p>2</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="stage-right2">
                <div class="plan-element">
                </div>
                <div class="plan-element">
                </div>
                <div class="plan-element">
                </div>
                <div class="plan-element">
                </div>
                <div class="plan-element">
                </div>
                <div class="plan-element">
                </div>
                <div class="plan-element">
                </div>
                <div class="plan-element add-plan-element">
                    <p>ADD</p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>




    </div>
```

Comment: This seems to be the correct answer. OP please mark this answer as correct so @imhvost can get the bounty and other people see that the question was answered.

Answer (score -1):

Columns defined in `grid-template-areas`, but not sized by `grid-template-columns`, are governed by `grid-auto-columns`.

From the spec:

> [§ 7.1. The Explicit
> Grid](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#explicit-grids)
>
> Any rows/columns defined by `grid-template-areas` but not sized by
> `grid-template-rows`/`grid-template-columns` take their size from the
> `grid-auto-rows`/`grid-auto-columns` properties.

The default value of `grid-auto-rows` and `grid-auto-columns` is [`auto`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#auto-tracks) (content length).

So (as indicated by @imhvost in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77412892/3597276)) just override that with `1fr`.

```css
#plan-container {
  max-width: 500px;
}

.stage {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 5fr;
  border-bottom: 3px solid grey;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.stage-left {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 4fr 2fr;
  text-align: center;
}

.stage-right {
  background-color: aqua;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 20px;
}

.stage2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "stage-left2 stage-left2 stage-right2 stage-right2 stage-right2 stage-right2 stage-right2";
  border-bottom: 3px solid grey;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr;  /* NEW  */
}

.stage-left2 {
  grid-area: stage-left2;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 4fr 2fr;
  text-align: center;
}

.stage-right2 {
  grid-area: stage-right2;
  background-color: aqua;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 20px;
}

.plan-element {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #555;
}

.add-plan-element {
  background-color: aqua;
}

.stage-left-numbering {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.stage-left-numbering p {
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="plan-container">
  <div class="stage">
    <div class="stage-left">
      <div class="stage-left-numbering">
        <p>1</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="stage-right">
      <div class="plan-element">
      </div>
      <div class="plan-element">
      </div>
      <div class="plan-element">
      </div>
      <div class="plan-element">
      </div>
      <div class="plan-element">
      </div>
      <div class="plan-element">
      </div>
      <div class="plan-element">
      </div>
      <div class="plan-element add-plan-element">
        <p>ADD</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="stage2">
    <div class="stage-left2">
      <div class="stage-left-numbering">
        <p>2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="stage-right2">
      <div class="plan-element">
      </div>
      <div class="plan-element">
      </div>
      <div class="plan-element">
      </div>
      <div class="plan-element">
      </div>
      <div class="plan-element">
      </div>
      <div class="plan-element">
      </div>
      <div class="plan-element">
      </div>
      <div class="plan-element add-plan-element">
        <p>ADD</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```